# How to fix incorrect data when loading from azure storage using external table in snowflake

Tags: parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage, external-tables

I was trying to load data from azure blob storage using snowflake's external table like this after creating the stage area(blob_tb2_434) :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydb.public.tb2_434
  WITH LOCATION = @mydb.public.blob_tb2_434/
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV  SKIP_HEADER = 1  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"' )
  PATTERN='.*.tsv';
```

The above external table will load every file with tsv extension from the blob defined in the stage area. I used FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY property because there are tabs, and other characters inside some of the fields enclosed with double quotes.

One of the files in the blob has `"A""` where it was supposed to be  `A"""` and the entire record is being read as null in the external table.
How can I use replace function from snowflake or other preprocessing to parse the data correctly?

I was trying to load the entire data using '\n' as the FIELD_DELIMITER and parsing it locally but it isn't working.

Comment: You can’t. You need to fix your data so that it has a valid format

Comment: You'd have more tricks available to you if you were loading the data using a COPY INTO command, but external tables don't offer you the ability to manipulate your data.  Is there a reason for using External Tables instead of loading the data to Snowflake directly?

Comment: What altering options can I use with COPY INTO command?

Comment: You could load the whole string in as a single column, and then parse it.  You could load the records that are valid and then manually load the records that show up in the `VALIDATE` function, which shows errored records.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate.html.

Lots of options that aren't necessarily available when leaving the data in a file.

Comment: Do I remove the FIELD_DELIMETER to load it as a single column?